# Executing jQuery .ready() function with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I am integrating DataTables jQuery plugin in an ASP.NET MVC 3 app. Inside jQuery `.ready()` function I am attaching DataTable to an existing Table.

Now, I need to load ASP.NET MVC dynamically. Where would be the best place to attach DataTable plugin on the dynamically loaded views? "Success" function of the $.get() would be a good place to attach the plugin after I've added the HTML to the DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `success` method as you mention. The key being that:

- The target `<table>` has been created.
- That table has the data loaded.

As long as the above criteria has been met, then go ahead and uses the `.datatable()` plugin.

I have a couple of MVC projects where I use this technique myself for updating the content of a table which then needs to become a DataTable (i.e. for sorting, searching, etc).

Comment: Thanks. do you find DataTable limiting? In a sense, I can't find my way adding a custom column, when user clicks on it, I display another Grid below. Is such a thing easily doable or requires bit of coding?

Comment: Interesting question. The API for the DataTables plugin is very thorough, but off the top of my head I don't know of a way to do that. You might want to ask a new question regarding this query you have?

Comment: That's a nice example. A colleague of mine may find that one very handy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the table data using AJAX then you should attach the datatable in the success callback of this AJAX call once it is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Totally off topic: @Darin congrats on becoming the #2 contributor on SO this week. Amazing stuff!